# How can I enumerate a hashtable as key-value pairs / filter a hashtable by a collection of key values

Tags: powershell, hashtable

<sup>**Editor's note:**
This question has a complicated history, but boils down to this:

* To learn how to ***enumerate* the entries of a hashtable by its *key-value pairs***, see [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635938/45375).

* To learn how to ***filter* a hashtable by a *collection of key values***, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37636001/45375).</sup>

---

I think I fell into the X Y problem again, my initial question was about Filtering a hash table. I discovered it's easier to filter before creating the hash table. Question answered, right?

Nope, the Y problem was looping each Key and using the Values which @briantist helped me with.

My goal is to loop over the key names, which are timestamps, and schedule a task using the key name as the task name and trigger.

I'm creating a hash table from a CSV file using `Group-Object -AsHashTable -AsString`  **-edit, it's worth mentioning here that filtering the CSV before creating the HashTable only makes things easier down the `Pipeline` or script**.

As an example:

```
Import-CSV (ls -path D:\ -Filter source*.csv | sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1).FullName |
 where {$_.TimeCorrected -ne 'ManualRebootServer'} |
 group TimeCorrected -AsHashTable -AsString
```

I'm trying to loop over the key names and able to display the key names using:

```
$var = Import-Csv csv123.csv | Group-Object Value1 -AsHashTable -AsString

foreach ($key in $var.Keys){"The key name is $key"}

#Create a scheduled task named and triggered based on the HashTable keyname
#test test test
foreach ($key in $var.keys){IF($key -ne 'ManualRebootServer'){"Register-ScheduledJob"}}
```

I'm just not sure how to get the values from the keys I am interested in.

I've found the following works, but only when I enter a Key name manually.  I'm just unsure how to combine both loops.

```
($val.GetEnumerator() | Where {$_.key -eq '06-11-16 18:00'} | ForEach-Object { $_.value }).Server
```

Comment: Just to offer an explanation, the filtering (at least in PowerShell) is always best accomplished before or to the left of the Pipeline operator `|` to make scripts more efficient.

Comment: Indeed; to put it differently: Using provider-native filtering with the `-Filter` parameter (if available) is usually much faster than passing unfiltered output through the pipeline in order to let the `Where-Object` cmdlet perform the filtering later.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have some options here.

Enumerating through keys:

```
foreach ($key in $var.Keys) {
    $value = $var[$key]
    # or
    $value = $var.$key 
}
```

Enumerating key-value pairs (which you've discovered, but may not be using effectively):

```
foreach ($kvp in $var.GetEnumerator()) {
    $key = $kvp.Key
    $val = $kvp.Value
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code in the first block, using an IF statement because there is a key I want to skip.  This works `$value = $val[$key].server` but I've got further filtering work that needs to be done after this.  Could it be as simple as putting the `$value` into an array and filter after the fact?

Comment: @user4317867 it would help if you would be more explicit in what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, as I can only speculate based on what you've said so far. "Further filtering work" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: Apologies, I put a half day into this question!  It's worth pointing out to filter the CSV before creating the hashtable, eg `Import-CSV file.csv | where {$_.Column -ne 'String'}` to make things easier down the line!

Comment: Neatly summarizes the 2 idioms to master.  It's a thousand pities Powershell doesn't have a less cumbersome .GetEnumerator().

Answer (score 16):

To complement [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635938/45375) by focusing on **filtering a hashtable by an array of key values** (PSv3+ syntax):

```
# Sample hashtable.
$ht = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

# Filter it by an array of key values; applying .GetEnumerator() yields an array
# of [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry] instances, which have
# a .Key property and a .Value property.
$ht.GetEnumerator()  | ? Key -in 'one', 'two'

# Similarly, the *output* - even though it *looks* like a hashtable - 
# is a regular PS *array* ([Object[]]) containing [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]
# entries (2 in this case).
$arrFilteredEntries = $ht.GetEnumerator()  | ? Key -in 'one', 'two'
$arrFilteredEntries.GetType().Name # -> Object[]
```

To further **process the matching key-value pairs**, simply pipe to `%` (`ForEach-Object`) and access `$_.Key` and `$_.Value` (value):

```
$ht.GetEnumerator()  | ? Key -in 'one', 'two' | 
  % { "Value for key '$($_.Key)': $($_.Value)" }
```

The equivalent command **using a more efficient `foreach` *loop*** instead of the pipeline:

```
foreach ($key in $ht.Keys) { 
  if ($key -in 'one', 'two') { "Value for key '$($key)': $($ht.$key)" }
}
```

<sup>Note: In **PSv2**:

* operator `-in` is not supported, but you can use `-contains` instead with the operands *swapped*:

`'one', 'two' -contains $key`

* in the pipeline, use `Where-Object { 'one', 'two' -contains $_.Key }`</sup>

With the sample hashtable, this yields:

```
Value for key 'two': 2
Value for key 'one': 1
```

<sup>Note how the key order in the output differs from the definition order; in PSv3+, you can create *ordered* hashtables (`[ordered] @{ ... }`) to preserve the definition order.</sup>

The key-filtering technique used above is *not* limited to filtering by *literal* key arrays; any (string) collection will do as the RHS of the `-in` operand, such as the `.Keys` collection of a *different* hashtable:

```
# Sample input hashtable.
$htInput = @{ one = 1; two = 2; three = 3 }

# Hashtable by whose keys the input hashtable should be filtered.
# Note that the entries' *values* are irrelevant here.
$htFilterKeys = @{ one = $null; two = $null }

# Perform filtering.
$htInput.GetEnumerator()  | ? Key -in $htFilterKeys.Keys | 
  % { "Value for key '$($_.Key)': $($_.Value)" }

# `foreach` loop equivalent:
foreach ($key in $htInput.Keys) {
  if ($key -in $htFilterKeys.Keys) { "Value for key '$($key)': $($htInput.$key)" }
}
```

The result is the same as in the example with the static filter-keys array.

Finally, if you want to **filter a hashtable *in place*** or **create a *new* hashtable with only the filtered entries**:

```
# *In-place* Updating of the hashtable.
# Remove entries other than the ones matching the specified keys.
# Note: The @(...) around $ht.Keys is needed to clone the keys collection before
# enumeration, so that you don't get an error about modifying a collection
# while it is being enumerated.
foreach ($key in @($ht.Keys)) { 
  if ($key -notin 'one', 'two') { $ht.Remove($key) } 
} 

# Create a *new* hashtable with only the filtered entries.
# By accessing the original's .Keys collection, the need for @(...) is obviated.
$htNew = $ht.Clone()
foreach ($key in $ht.Keys) { 
  if ($key -notin 'one', 'two') { $htNew.Remove($key) }
}
```

---

As an aside:

The default output format for `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]` (and thus hashtables (`[System.Collections.Hashtable]`) uses column name `Name` rather than `Key`; `Name` is defined as an *alias property* of `Key` added by *PowerShell* (it is not part of the [`[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`.NET type definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry.aspx); verify with
`@{ one = 1 }.GetEnumerator() | Get-Member`).