# How to iterate through a hashtable which contains multi arrays with key, values and append it with another string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a hashtable with the below structure,

```
$testHsh = @{2 = (1,3);3 = (2,4,6)}
```

I'm trying to iterate the above hashtable and wanted to concatenate the string "testmachine-" with the values of keys(2 & 3)and trying to save the values in another hashtable like below,

```
$tm = @{2 = (testmachine-1,testmachine-3,testmachine-5);3 = (testmachine-2,testmachine-4,testmachine-6)}
```

Here is my code to achieve my objective,

```
$teststr= "testmachine-"
$testInfo = $null
$machineHash = @{}
foreach ($ts in $testHsh.Count) {
    $testInfo = @()
    for($i=0;$i -lt $ts.Values;$i = $i+1) {
    $testInfo += @($teststr+ $ts)
    Write-Output $testInfo
    }
    $testInfoSet = @{$ts = $testInfo}
    $testInfoObj = New-Object psobject -Property $testInfoSet
    $machineHash = $testtInfoObj
}

Write-Output $machineHash
```

Please suggest the best method to achieve my objective! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635820/how-can-i-enumerate-a-hashtable-as-key-value-pairs-filter-a-hashtable-by-a-col/37635938) to learn more about enumerating hashtables.

How I'd do it:

```
$testHsh.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    $machineHash[$_.Key] = $_.Value | foreach {"$teststr$_"}
}
```

If you need more explanation, let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`$testHsh.Count` is an integer, not a collection you can iterate over.

Instead, you'll want to call `GetEnumerator()` on the source hashtable:

```
# define source hashtable 
$testHsh = @{2 = (1,3,5);3 = (2,4,6)}

# define new destination hashtable 
$machineHash = @{}

# loop over each name-value entry in $testHsh
foreach($entry in $testHsh.GetEnumerator()){
  # Assign to the same key in the destination hash, an array of the values from the source, but modified
  $machineHash[$entry.Name] = @(
    # prefix all values from source hash entry with "testmachine-"
    $entry.Value |ForEach-Object {
        "testmachine-${_}"
    }
  )
}

$machineHash
```

Comment: Upon trying the above method I get the below hashtable

$machineHash = @{2 = (testmachine-) ; 3 = (testmachine-)}

Values of 2 & 3 keys were not appended with the string

Comment: Did you forget to define the values in `$testHsh` as described in your question?

Comment: it worked actually that was my mistake, but the hashtable is in a reverse format like below.

$testHsh = @{2 = (1,3,5);3 = (2,4,6)} 

but the output I got is 

 $machineHash = @{3 = (testmachine-2, testmachine-4, testmachine-6) ; 3 = (testmachine-1, testmachine-3, testmachine-5)}

Comment: @DjangoUnchained Hashtables don't preserve input order, you need an ordered dictionary for that (`$testHsh = [ordered]@{2 = ...}`)