# Replace string according to hashtable - Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, hashtable

I've got this weird problem here :

Here's my hashtable (about Morse Code):

```
$replacementDecodeMap = @{
    ' ● ― ' = 'a'
    ' ― ● ● ● ' = 'b'
    ' ― ● ― ● ' = 'c'
    ' ― ● ● ' = 'd'
    ' ● ' = 'e'
    ' ● ● ― ● ' = 'f'
    ' ― ― ● ' = 'g'
    ' ● ● ● ● ' = 'h'
    ' ● ● ' = 'i'
    ' ● ― ― ― ' = 'j'
    ' ― ● ― ' = 'k'
    ' ● ― ● ● ' = 'l'
    ' ― ― ' = 'm'
    ' ― ● ' = 'n'
    ' ― ― ― ' = 'o'
    ' ● ― ― ● ' = 'p'
    ' ― ― ● ― ' = 'q'
    ' ● ― ● ' = 'r'
    ' ● ● ● ' = 's'
    ' ― ' = 't'
    ' ● ● ― ' = 'u'
    ' ● ● ● ― ' = 'v'
    ' ● ― ― ' = 'w'
    ' ― ● ● ― ' = 'x'
    ' ― ● ― ― ' = 'y'
    ' ― ― ● ● ' = 'z'
    ' ● ― ― ― ― ' = '1'
    ' ● ● ― ― ― ' = '2'
    ' ● ● ● ― ― ' = '3'
    ' ● ● ● ● ― ' = '4'
    ' ● ● ● ● ● ' = '5'
    ' ― ● ● ● ● ' = '6'
    ' ― ― ● ● ● ' = '7'
    ' ― ― ― ● ● ' = '8'
    ' ― ― ― ― ● ' = '9'
    ' ― ― ― ― ― ' = '0'
    ' ● ● ― ― ● ● ' = '?'
    ' ― ● ― ● ― ― ' = '!'
    ' ● ― ● ― ● ― ' = '.'
    ' ― ― ● ● ― ― ' = ','
    ' ― ● ― ● ― ● ' = "'"
    ' ― ― ― ● ● ● ' = ':'
    ' ● ― ● ― ● '= '+'
    ' ― ● ● ● ● ― ' = '-'
    ' ― ● ● ― ● ' = '÷'
    ' * ― ' = 'a'
    ' ― * * * ' = 'b'
    ' ― * ― * ' = 'c'
    ' ― * * ' = 'd'
    ' * ' = 'e'
    ' * * ― * ' = 'f'
    ' ― ― * ' = 'g'
    ' * * * * ' = 'h'
    ' * * ' = 'i'
    ' * ― ― ― ' = 'j'
    ' ― * ― ' = 'k'
    ' * ― * * ' = 'l'
    ' ― * ' = 'n'
    ' * ― ― * ' = 'p'
    ' ― ― * ― ' = 'q'
    ' * ― * ' = 'r'
    ' * * * ' = 's'
    ' * * ― ' = 'u'
    ' * * * ― ' = 'v'
    ' * ― ― ' = 'w'
    ' ― * * ― ' = 'x'
    ' ― * ― ― ' = 'y'
    ' ― ― * * ' = 'z'
    ' * ― ― ― ― ' = '1'
    ' * * ― ― ― ' = '2'
    ' * * * ― ― ' = '3'
    ' * * * * ― ' = '4'
    ' * * * * * ' = '5'
    ' ― * * * * ' = '6'
    ' ― ― * * * ' = '7'
    ' ― ― ― * * ' = '8'
    ' ― ― ― ― * ' = '9'
    ' * * ― ― * * ' = '?'
    ' ― * ― * ― ― ' = '!'
    ' * ― * ― * ― ' = '.'
    ' ― ― * * ― ― ' = ','
    ' ― * ― * ― * ' = "'"
    ' ― ― ― * * * ' = ':'
    ' * ― * ― * '= '+'
    ' ― * * * * ― ' = '-'
    ' ― * * ― * ' = '÷'
    ' ' = ' '
}
```

I have decomposed my message into an array, so each letter or space corresponds to a line.

Now I am trying to replace the contents of the lines according to the hastable.

This process loops round the number of times of the array :

```
    [array]$inparts = @()
    $inparts = $message.split("/")
    [array]$outparts = @(0) * $inparts.Length
    $ntimes = 0
    
    do {
        foreach ($e in $replacementDecodeMap) {
            $in = $inparts[$ntimes]
            $out = $in -replace $e.Name, $e.Value
            $outparts[$ntimes] = $out
        }
        $ntimes = $ntimes + 1
    } until (
         ($ntimes - 1) -eq $inparts.Length
    )

    Write-Host $outparts
```

The problem with that is that it doesn't replace anything, it just copies over the lines of the array...

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here...
Please help me.

EDIT :

Here is an example message :  `― ― / ― ● ― ― // ― ● / ● ― / ― ― / ● // ● ● / ● ● ● // ● ● ● / ● ● / ● ― ● ● / ● ― ● ● / ― ― ― / ― ● ― / ― ● ― ― /` (it means "my name is silloky").

```
PS > $inparts = $message.split("/")
PS > $inparts
  ― ―
 ●

 ● ●
 ● ● ●

 ● ● ●
 ● ●
 ● ― ● ●
 ● ― ● ●
 ― ― ―
 ― ● ―
 ― ● ― ―
PS > [array]$outparts = @(0) * $inparts.Length
PS > $outparts
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
```

The idea is to end up with (and so have the Morse code message decoded):

```
PS > $outparts
 m
 y
  #that's a space here
 n
 a
 m
 e
  #that's a space here
 i
 s
  #that's a space here
 s
 i
 l
 l
 o
 k
 y
PS > $outmessage = $outparts -join ""
PS > $outmessage
 my name is silloky

#YAY, IT WORKS... no this is just me writing what the code should do...
```

This might not be the best way to make a Morse code decoder, but I'm supposed to build this by myself, so I even if you propose a completely different solution than mine, I will discard it (but that doesn't mean I won't be interested to read it...)

Comment: Can you show us a sample `$message` value?

Comment: ```foreach( $e in $replacementDecodeMap )``` for a hashtable *doesn't* enumerate the key-value pairs - instead it loops *once* with the hashtable itself as the loop variable. You probably want ```foreach( $e in $replacementDecodeMap.GetEnumerator() )```. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635938/3156906 for other options...

Comment: Looks to me that the iteration isn't even required: Remove all the spaces from the names of the given `$replacementDecodeMap` hash table, then just do: `$inparts.ForEach{ $replacementDecodeMap[$_ -Replace '\s'] }`

Comment: Do you mind writing answers with code blocks, it might be easier for me, thanks !

Comment: your message gives me `ynameissilloky` instead of `my name is...`, after splitting on `/` you can simply do `[string]::new($replacementDecodeMap[$message])`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the problem about that is that if I have `- - - ` (which is o), it will output `mt` because `- -` is m and `-` is t ; it won't understand i want to analyse the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint for a simpler solution - instead of looping over all the entries in your map, break the message down into individual parts like you've already done, but then use a `for` loop over *those* and look them up one by one in the map to find which character they represent.

You'll need to add handling for converting the empty string into a space as well.

Adding spoiler tags in case you want to try that approach yourself before you peek :-)...

> ```
>  $message = " ― ― / ― ● ― ― // ― ● / ● ― / ― ― / ● // ● ● / ● ● ● // ● ● ● / ● ● / ● ― ● ● / ● ― ● ● / ― ― ― / ― ● ― / ― ● ― ― /";
>
>  $parts = $message.Split("/");
>
>  $letters = $parts | foreach-object {
>      $item = $_;
>      if( $item -eq [string]::Empty )
>      {
>          write-output " ";
>      }
>      elseif( -not $replacementDecodeMap.ContainsKey($item) )
>      {
>          throw "code '$item' isn't defined in the map";
>      }
>      write-output $replacementDecodeMap[$item];
>  }
>
>  $letters -join ""
>  # my name is silloky
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; to be honest i have no idea what you're talking about, so i might also look under the grey veil...

Comment: ```$inparts = $message.split("/"); foreach( $inpart in $inparts ) { # convert this part into a letter }```

Comment: Yeah, would never have been able to get to that myself : still haven't completely understood piping...

Comment: What does this mean : `$code = $_;` ?

Comment: The pipeline isn't the key here - you could do it with a ```foreach``` loop as well. The main difference is looping over ```$inpart``` rather than ```$replacementDecodeMap```.

Comment: ```$_``` is the "context variable" - in a ```foreach-object``` scriptblock it means "the current loop variable". Similar to ```foreach( $code in $codes ) { ... }```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246399/discussion-between-silloky-and-mclayton).

Comment: Is it a typo or are $codes and $code suppose to be different ?

Comment: @Silloky - it's not a typo - ```$codes```(plural)  was your original ```$inparts```, and ```$code``` (singular) is the loop variable. I've renamed it to ```$parts``` and```$item``` in the answer though to make it more obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how stackoverflow points really work, but I hope you'll get some because you've a real lifesaver ! 